# Codeigniter returning code 0 db errors without message

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli, transactions

I have a query that is supposed to return an error message like this:

```
Error Number: 1451    
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sservice_dev_mercury`.`agent_accounts`, CONSTRAINT `agent_role_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`role`) REFERENCES `roles` (`id`))    
DELETE FROM `roles` WHERE `id` = '3'
```

This is when `db_debug` is true. When I turned it false and used

```
$error = $this->db->error();
return $error;
```

I get error 0 with an empty message. Is there something I am missing when trying to get the errors? This is the query:

```
public function delete($id){
     $this->db->trans_begin();
     $this->db->where('id',$id);
     $this->db->delete($this->table);
     $this->db->trans_complete();
     if($this->db->trans_status()===false){
        $this->db->trans_rollback();
        $error = $this->db->error();
        return $error;
     }else{
        $this->db->trans_commit();
        return true;
     }
}
```

Can someone take a look and see if something went wrong?

Comment: Problem is in database tables' relations. Can you post schema of both tables and tell us wich one is `$this->table`.

Comment: Oh. I know its the table issue. I just want this error to come out as a message instead of taking up the entire page. I purposely set it up that way.

Comment: You should customise [this method](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/DB_driver.php#L574-L660) according to your needs. Zero is returned because of line [659](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/DB_driver.php#L659). Of course, you should extend class without making changes in system files. Maybe you can try that way.

Comment: hi! thanks for replying. How do i extend it?

Comment: Read [docs and this full page](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html), (particularly [this section](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html#extending-native-libraries)).

Comment: Hi, I tried to edit the line to return the error codes but it still returns empty for some reason.

Comment: I read your question again. Please answer why would you turn off db_debug? I am asking because it is just it - output of error you see when it is set to true.

Comment: Because I am trying to pass the error as a text message line that appears in a <div> instead of taking up an entire error page.

Comment: Try to put `$this->db->error();` before `$this->db->trans_rollback();`.

Comment: Still doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: If you turn on error logging `($config['log_threshold'] = 1;` in application/config.php) and db_debug off does the error get written to the log file?

Answer (score 1):

The user has mentioned that he wants to get the error in the database transaction. so for that, I found only this solution to the problem, but It is quite verbose:

```
try {
  $this->db->trans_begin();
  $res = $this->db->where('id',$id)->delete($this->table);   
  if(!$res) throw new Exception($this->db->_error_message(), $this->db->_error_number());
  $this->db->trans_commit();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
  $this->db->trans_rollback();
  log_message('error', sprintf('%s : %s : DB transaction failed. Error no: %s, Error msg:%s, Last query: %s', __CLASS__, __FUNCTION__, $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage(), print_r($this->main_db->last_query(), TRUE)));
}
```

Please note that

- I am using the "manual transaction" mode of CI,
- I have to call `$this->db->_error_message()`, `$this->db->_error_number()` after each query, because it returns an empty response in the catch block.

This way you can achieve the detailed error handling.

[Here](https://forum.codeigniter.com/archive/index.php?thread-1255.html) is the reference link.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this method. So far other methods don't seem to work

Comment: @JianYA  may be, I am not sure. I will get back to you after some testing.

Comment: Hello, The new method is to use $this->db->error(); It will work only without transactional items such as trans_begins and only can work with one query. Do you know if it can work with multiple?